# Bluetooth EDR Connection; Loss of Signal; What Spec or Stack parameter determines the time to broken connection

Tags: bluetooth

Assume we have two Bluetooth devices talking to each other as continuously as possible. Assume we are using SPP serial port profile.  We interrupt the RF signal between these two devices perfectly. What part of the specification or what stack parameter gives the number of the seconds for each device to report a broken connection.

The specific part implementing the bluetooth connection is an STM antenna-to-serial port module with stock firmware.

The context of the question is to verify a specification.  My knowledge is limited to a stack that has TCP/IP-like events.